# Extract value in last bracket

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How could I extract the country from a Google Sheet column? i.e. the value in the final bracket

```
Paper (Brazil)
Table (J) (UK)
Pen (Spain)
```

Expected Output:

```
Brazil
UK
Spain
```

I tried:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"\((.*)\)$")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try nested `REGEXEXTRACT()`.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(REGEXEXTRACT(A2,".+\s(.+)") ,"\((.*)\)$")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. Some countries also have a dot on the end e.g. ("Germany."). Is there a quick way to deal with this in the same formula?

Answer (score 0):

You may also try:

```
=index(ifna(regexextract(A2:A,".*\s\((\w+)\W*?\)")))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For a single cell you can use:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(\w+)\W+$")
```

For a whole range, this one:

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A6,"(\w+)\W+$")))
```

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

---

- `\w` Matches any letter, digit or underscore
- `\W` Matches anything **other than** a letter, digit or underscore.
- `+`  Matches one or more consecutive characters

Functions used:

- [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)